# sendmail: Using alternative port with smart-host

Tags: debian, sendmail, mail-transport-agent

Sendmail not following smart_host alternative port macro.
Using Exchange server, exchange.redacted.com, we are using port 2525 for internal devices and some Linux based machines, allowing them send outgoing email without authentication. The 'receive connector' allows relay for devices on our intranet and external with explicit IP address authorization.
Linux based devices MTA is **sendmail**.

I edited `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` adding:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[exchange.redacted.com]')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
define(`SMTP_MAILER_ARGS' , `TCP $h 2525')dnl
define(`SMTP8_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
define(`DSMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
```

Just in case, I added all the _***MAILER_ARGS** trying to specify the port to use with no success.

The generated **sendmail.cf**, shows the **SMART_HOST** selected but not the alternative port.

```
# "Smart" relay host (may be null)
DSrelay:[exchange.redacted.com]
...
Mrelay,     P=[IPC], F=mDFMuXa8, S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=MasqSMTP/MasqRelay, E=\r\n, L=2040,
      T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
      A=TCP $h
```

modifying the Mrelay, adding 2525 works as intended:

```
Mrelay,     P=[IPC], F=mDFMuXa8, S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=MasqSMTP/MasqRelay, E=\r\n, L=2040,
      T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
      A=TCP $h 2525
```

How can I specify the port on the **.mc** source without the need of a manual edit the resultant **.cf**?

Comment: Have you defined RELAY_MAILER_ARGS in sendmail.mc file **before** MAILER(smtp)? [The trivial reason to rule out before checking more sinister exaplanations]

Comment: yes. I did. I place it at the top. In fact, looks like the the only `MAILER_ARGS` processed is  `SMTP_MAILER_ARGS`. I check also `smtp.m4` and I can't find a good reason to fail

Comment: Try to get help via `news:comp.mail.sendmail`

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `sendmail.mc` file by adding the following line.

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `host.domain.com')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS',`TCP $h 2525')
dnl # Above line for Smart Relay to use Port 2525 instead of 25
```

Make sure to change the first line to the relay server hostname domain that is running SMTP Port `2525`.

Run the following command in your /etc/mail directory to update your sendmail.cf

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```